# How to get subqueries from FROM clause using Jsql Parser?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, jsqlparser

I have a sample sql query like

```
String Q1 = "SELECT field1 
             from (
                 SELECT count(field2) 
                 from table2  
                 UNION SELECT count(fileld3) 
                 from table3
             )";
```

i need to get FROM clause  from sql using jsql parser where i need to remove unwanted parathesis?

I tried the following

```
Select select = (Select) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);
PlainSelect pl = (PlainSelect) select.getSelectBody();
String from_clause= pl.getFromItem().toString();
System.out.println(from_clause);
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Looks ok. Using visitors would be definitly more code. Where do would like to improve? Why do you ask? Is there a problem?

Comment: ((SubSelect)plainSelect.getFromItem()).getSelectBody().toString() this is the better option.